# Align an icon to the right of the border

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my icon to always be centered vertically with the paragraph it's next to. I don't want it to be indented like you see in the example.

Here's what I have so far:

```
.note {
    border-left: 4px solid #42b983;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .test {
    position: relative;
    left: -12px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 19px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

And it's showing up like this:

[image]

But I'm going for something more like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: make a reproducible example, or show html, pls

Comment: HTML: <p class ="note"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o test"></i> Any information added here will override the lecture’s automated pricing information when viewing pricing on the Announcement Page.</p>

Answer (score 1):

For the icon to take the full height of your container, the container itself needs to be in flex. From there, this will allow you to align the icon and text however you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <style>
    .note {
        border-left: 4px solid #42b983;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        display:flex;
        align-content:center;
      }

      .test {
        position: relative;
        margin-right:10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
    </style>

    <body>
        <p class ="note"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o test">o</i> Any information added here will override the lecture’s automated pricing information when viewing pricing on the Announcement Page.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a lot better than I had but it still isn't aligned vertically with the paragraph to the right. I'll keep poking around to see if I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
    .note {
        border-left: 4px solid #42b983;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        display:flex;
        align-content:center;
      }

      .test {
        position: relative;
        margin-right:10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   

    <body>
        <div class ="note"><i class="test">o</i>
           <p>Any information added here will override the lecture’s<br> automated pricing information when viewing pricing<br> on the Announcement Page.</p>
           </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with this solution?

Comment: you tag `i` indicated outside `p`

Answer (score 0):

I added a reference to **fontAwesome**. Set up flex centering rules for tag `<p>` - `.note` class:

```
.note {
    ...
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Now, according to the code you provided, you get the correct vertical centering.

```css
.note {
    border-left: 4px solid #42b983;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.test {
    height: 19px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/js/all.js"></script>

<p class ="note">
  <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o test"></i>Any information added here will override the lecture’s automated pricing information when viewing pricing on the Announcement Page.
</p>
```